# Oracle Accessing updated records during the same transaction

Tags: oracle, transactions

Using Oracle 10g

Is it possible to get the value of a newly updated field within the same transaction before it is committed.

I am executing a stored procedure which calls 2 other stored procedures.

The first stored procedure gets a record from a table and then updates that record.

The second stored procedure gets that same record but needs to use the newly updated fields from the first stored procedure.

Then the commit is carried out.

The commit can only be done if both procedures are carried out sucessfully.

Will the second stored procedure get the newly updated data or will it get a copy of the same data that was returned in the first procedure without the update ?

Comment: If everything is truly one transaction, procedure 2 simply needs to select the rows in question. It *will* see the current (updated) values.

Comment: @lan:You can return the record from the first proc as OUT parameter and use that record as IN parameter in second Proc

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was hoping you would say that. Thank you.

Comment: @GauravSoni thank you but I was hoping that I didnt need to modify the parameters for the procedures.

Comment: @lan Jordan:In that case make the variable as `Global variable`,if and only if your all three proc are in the `same pakage` ,but there is no harm in modifying the parameter of proc ,infact that make the code readible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a very simple and robust implementation of read consistency:

- a user sees the latest version of the data, including any changes made by the current transaction, but ...
- a user cannot see the changes made by any other user until that other user issues a commit, and even then not until executing a new statement.

This is covered in the Concepts Guide.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#sthref1925).