# Using cursor after a delete statement in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, transactions, plsql, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle Accessing updated records during the same transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514303/oracle-accessing-updated-records-during-the-same-transaction)

I have an Oracle stored procedure somewhat like this (actual sqls are different)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mysp
IS
v_copied_row table%ROWTYPE ;

 CURSOR p_copied_rows IS
 select *
 from table ;

BEGIN
  delete from table
where <some condition>

OPEN p_copied_rows ;
LOOP
FETCH p_copied_rows into v_copied_rows ;
<do something with fetched row>
END LOOP
close p_copied_rows;
END;
```

Ideally, I am expecting that the deleted rows should not be part of the result set I am fetching from the cursor, but those are.

I am new to oracle, and want to understand if i am doing something wrong here?

P.S. I've to use cursor for some complex things, so replacing cursor with the SQL is not an option.

Comment: My bad. I've missed a statement while running thie above procedure.  Moderator can delete/close this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual code matched the code you posted, the rows you you delete would not be returned by the cursor

If I create a table with 100 rows

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table foo
  2  as
  3  select level col1
  4    from dual
  5* connect by level <= 100
SQL> /

Table created.
```

and then create a PL/SQL block that replicates what you posted which deletes 98 of the rows, the cursor that is opened will return only 2 rows

```
SQL> select count(*) from foo;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       100

SQL> declare
  2    cursor non_deleted_rows
  3        is select *
  4             from foo;
  5    l_rec foo%rowtype;
  6  begin
  7    delete from foo
  8     where col1 <= 98;
  9
 10    open non_deleted_rows;
 11    loop
 12      fetch non_deleted_rows into l_rec;
 13      exit when non_deleted_rows%notfound;
 14
 15      dbms_output.put_line( l_rec.col1 );
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /
99
100

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now, if you open the cursor before you issue the `DELETE`, the cursor will return the rows that were deleted.  Perhaps in your actual code, the `OPEN` statement is before the `DELETE`.